# How much hashrate is rquired to generate 1 ETH in two days

Tags: mining, solo-mining, rig

I want to make my own rig and want to mine 1 ETH in two days. But I need precise hash rate requirements, I asked Google Bard it gives different hash rates on every prompt. ChatGPT is not giving any calculations. Can anybody help? Secondly, also give me the rig specs as well I want to use Intel 19-13900K and RTX 4090s

Comment: Firstly ChatGpt and similar tools are generated on data that can be old so they can give you out-of-date results. One thing they should point out is that Ethereum has moved to proof of stake meaning that now you need 32ETH to participate in mining instead of strong hardware. You can still run your own node, but instead of strong computing power you need high uptime. Read more here: https://ethereum.org/en/staking/solo/

Comment: Thank you very much But I want to run my own node actually instead of staking it

Answer (score 2):

Ethereum has transitioned proof-of-stake, so you cannot mine anymore.

Comment: Thank you, but can you give me more information on running a node? I have read it on website but I am curious how much time will it take to 32 ETH (for staking). I mean I do not want to buy 32 ETH I do not have that much investment.

Comment: You can stake without running your own node and with less than 32 ETH [by using a liquid staking service like StakeWise](https://stakewise.io/). This is a good for someone who is not an expert in this field. If yo want to run your solo validator on your own server, you need to stake minimum of 32 ETH.